# Fill non-static variable in static class (Spinner)

Tags: android, variables, static, non-static

I am trying to make this:

1. In DatePickerDialog user set a date
2. Date will be written in Spinner

The problem is that DatePickerFragment class which includes OnDateSet method is static and the spinner is non-static. In OnDateSet method I need to add item to adapter and call method Spinner.setSelection(int i)

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

           @Override
           public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
               final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
               int year1 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-25;
               int month1 = 0;
               int day1 = 1;


               // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
               return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year1, month1, day1);
           }

           public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year1, int month1, int day1) {
               firstdate = day1 + "/" + month1 + "/" + year1;
           }

       }
```

The error is in this line:

```
firstdate = day1 + "/" + month1 + "/" + year1;
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: firstdate is not declared

Comment: Yes it is outside a class

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it also inside your fragment, and have a getter that returns its value;

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

 private int firstdate;

 // .. other code

 public int getFirstDate() {
    return firstdate;
 }

}
```

and from your activity, [onDissmiss](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onDismiss%28android.content.DialogInterface%29) you can call it like `mDialogInstance.getFirstDate();`